# calculating dates from months

Tags: sql, t-sql

This table acts like a history of where someone works.
Where TypeID = 1 is the current place of work, so EndDate is todays date and StartDate is when then they started, worked out based on the Months column.

Where TypeID = 2 is where they used to work so EndDate is 1 day less than the StartDate of the first record and  StartDate for TypeID of 2 should be when they stared that job, i.e. 24 months ago.

Table format

```
create table #test (startdate date, enddate date, months int, typeid int, account int)
insert into #test values (NULL,getdate(), 12, 1, 12345)
insert into #test values (NULL,NULL, 24, 2, 12345)
```

Output Results

```
create table #test (startdate date, enddate date, months int, typeid int, account int)
insert into #test values ('2017-11-02',getdate(), 12, 1, 12345)
insert into #test values ('2015-11-1','2017-11-01', 24, 2, 12345)

startdate   enddate     months  typeid  account
2017-11-02  2018-11-02  12      1       12345
2015-11-01  2017-11-01  24      2       12345
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Sample data and desired results -- in a text table -- would help.

Comment: I can't follow your descrition, it's confusing.

Comment: That first sentence is a brain melter. I've had a few cracks at it and none of them work, it just comes off as complete nonsense. Can you rewrite, with some punctuation, or perhaps some pseudo-code?

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment with still a lot of assumptions from the question

Is #test and #testa supposed to be different tables? I assume you've populated #test correctly and can populate #testa with something like,

```
create table #test (startdate date, enddate date, months int, typeid int, account int)
insert into #test values (NULL,getdate(), 12, 1, 12345)
insert into #test values (NULL,NULL, 24, 2, 12345)

create table #testa (startdate date, enddate date, months int, typeid int, account int)

INSERT INTO #testa
SELECT DATEADD(month, months*-1, enddate), enddate, months, typeid, account
FROM #test
WHERE typeid = 1

INSERT INTO #testa
SELECT DATEADD(month, months*-1, DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())), DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()), months, typeid, account
FROM #test
WHERE typeid = 2

SELECT * FROM #testa

DROP TABLE #test
DROP TABLE #testa
```

This can be done through an update statement on #test if you don't need #testa.
This can also be done with case statements in a single query. I've left it as two to try to understand if this answer is on the correct path.